# Associate additional extension with existing lexer

Tags: python, pygments, pygmentize

Is there an easy way to add a filename and/or extension for existing lexer in pygments? I don't want to write or subclass existing one, as the language is the same, but the file has different extension/name.

I've tried to hack it and add it to the `filenames` class variable (somewhere in `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/agile.py`), but for some reason it didn't worked.

I was wondering for something like `.pygments` file, where users can associate additional names with the lexers, but looks like it's not possible right now.

What is the best way to achieve my goal then?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've found solution: after adding filenames/extensions to required Lexer you have to regenerate the mapping:

```
cd /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygments/lexers/; sudo python _mapping.py; cd -
```

This is not 100% clean solution, as in case of package update your changes will gone, but it pretty quick and easy.